# How can i call a function in activity from another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, sendmessage

I have a problem about sending sms in android. I have two classes. one of them is SendMessage.java and other one is SendingSms.java and I want to send my messages by SendingSms.java file so there is a sendSms class in it and I want to use this sendSms function in SendMessage.java file but it couldn't be. In addition I can use function that is in SendingSms.java but when I wrote send sms codes in it, it doesn't work. What's the problem?

here is function that is in my SendMessage.java

```
public void sendMessageButton (View view)
{
    //SendingSms send = new SendingSms();       
    if(who_detail.getText().toString().length()>0 && message_text.getText().toString().length()>0 )
    {
        sendSMS(who_detail.getText().toString(), message_text.getText().toString());

    }
    else
    {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sendingsms_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

here is my sendinSms.java

```
package com.example.stildeneme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendingSms extends Activity {

     public void sendSMS(String telNo, String mesaj)
        {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(getResultCode())
                    {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Gönderildi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                  
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS iletildi",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS iletilemedi",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));       

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(telNo, null, mesaj, sentPI, deliveredPI);

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), telNo.toString() + " - " + mesaj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

By the way, i extended my SendMessage class from SendingSms class.

here is my logcat

```
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     ... 11 more
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User 10048 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.example.stildeneme.SendingSms.sendSMS(SendingSms.java:69)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.example.stildeneme.SendMessage.sendMessageButton(SendMessage.java:76)
11-30 09:48:09.613: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you paste some code? I would be easier ;-)

Comment: maybe you can post some code?

Comment: i edited my question, codes in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the method as public static which you are going to access from another activity. then 
call it as activity1.sendsms();

This is the way . if you post the code will advice you better way... hope this will help you .

**Hi use the below code. the thing is you need to use Context.**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendingSms extends Activity {

    static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context=this;

    }

     public static void sendSMS(String telNo, String mesaj)
        {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(getResultCode())
                    {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Gönderildi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                         Toast.makeText(context, "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                  
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


            context. registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS iletildi",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS iletilemedi",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));       

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(telNo, null, mesaj, sentPI, deliveredPI);

         Toast.makeText(context, telNo.toString() + " - " + mesaj.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. But there is a problem, if i make sendSms function static, I'm getting error.

Comment: hi it seems you are not added the  permission . please add it .  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Comment: Ah, silly me, i forgot it, i was in war with this :) Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

First intialize the class in your sendMessage.java

sendinsms sm=new sendinsms();

sm.sendsms(your parameter);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing one permission:

```
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User
> 10048 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
```

Secondly, this method should not be `static` - you can have a memory leak.

If you SendMessage extends SendSms you should make SendSms.sendSms method public  and it should work

You should not use: `static Context context;`

`context` should be a normal field. And why you need it :>? You can use `activity context`

Answer (score 0):

you can do in two ways :

**1.** pass the context of the activity in which the method is present into the other activity where you want to call the method.

**2.** second way is to make the method static and then call it from other activity using classname with . operator

**Eg:**

`Class_Name.method()`